# Number of iterations needed to attain a given precision $10^{-b}$ in Newton-Raphton method.

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I need to derive a formula to calculate the number of iterations needed to find $\sqrt{a}$ with a given accuracy of $10^{-8}$. The following is also given: $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a}{x})$, $a\in (1,100)$ and $x_0=10$. So

$$x_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}}\right)$$

How can I derive a formula to calculate the number of iterations needed? An answer to a similar question can be found here: [Minimum number of iterations in Newton's method to find a square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/558145/minimum-number-of-iterations-in-newtons-method-to-find-a-square-root). However the accuracy level there is $2^{-b}$ not $10^{-b}$. How should it be modified then? Also a big chunk of that proof isn't that clear to me. To be more precise (no pun intended) everything starting with

> If you want to achieve $2^{−b}$ relative accura$\ldots$

is hazy (Why is $x_n=(1+2^{-b})\sqrt{y}$? Why is $2^n=\frac{\ldots}{\ldots}$?). Can anyone explain the linked answer or provide a better one? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the linked answer was quite elegant, but let's go back to basics. The relative error is
$$\begin{align}e_n&=\left|\frac{\text{The value you've got}-\text{The exact value}}{\text{The exact value}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{x_n-\sqrt y}{\sqrt y}\right|=\frac{x_n-\sqrt y}{\sqrt y}\le10^{-b}\end{align}$$
Where I have dropped the absolute value bars because after the first iteration $x_n>\sqrt y$. This is equivalent to $x_n-\sqrt y\le10^{-b}\sqrt y$ or $x_n=(1+10^{-b})\sqrt y$.

Error refinement looks like this: given a relative error $e_n$ at step $n$ we see that $x_n=(1+e_n)\sqrt y$. Then
$$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=(1+e_{n+1})\sqrt y=\frac12\left(x_n+\frac y{x_n}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left((1+e_n)\sqrt y+\frac y{(1+e_n)\sqrt y}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left((1+e_n)\sqrt y+\sqrt y(1+e_n)^{-1}\right)\\
&\approx\frac{\sqrt y}2\left(1+e_n+1-e_n+e_n^2\right)=\sqrt y\left(1+\frac12e_n^2\right)\end{align}$$
It follows that $e_{n+1}\approx\frac12e_n^2$. Taking natural logarithms, $\ln e_{n+1}=2\ln e_n-\ln2$. If we let $Z_n=\ln e_n$ we have a linear difference equation for $Z_n$:
$$Z_{n+1}=2Z_n-\ln2$$
We first solve the homogeneous equation:
$$Z_{n+1,h}=2Z_{n,h}$$
By assuming a solution of the form $Z_{n,h}=Cr^n$. This leads to $Cr^{n+1}=2Cr^n$ or $r=2$, so $Z_{n,h}=C2^n$. Then we find a particular solution to the equation; we will guess $Z_{n,p}=A$, a constant. Then
$$Z_{n+1,p}=A=2Z_{n,p}-\ln2=2A-\ln2$$
With solution $Z_{n,p}=A=\ln2$. So now we put together
$$\ln e_n=Z_n=Z_{n,h}+Z_{n,p}=C2^n+\ln2$$
Applying the initial conditions $\ln e_0=C+\ln2$ we find that $C=\ln\frac{e_0}2$ so
$$\ln e_n=\left(\ln\frac{e_0}2\right)2^n+\ln2$$
And finally
$$e_n=2\left(\frac{e_0}2\right)^{2^n}\le10^{-8}$$
It's possible to get an initial estimate with relative error $e_0=0.03$ thus
$2(0.015)^{2^n}\le10^{-8}$ so $(0.015)^{2^n}\le5\times10^{-9}$ or $2^n\ln0.015\le\ln5\times10^{-9}$ or $2^n\ge\frac{\ln5\times10^{-9}}{\ln0.015}$ or
$$n\ge\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\ln5\times10^{-9}}{\ln0.015}\right)}{\ln2}\approx2.19$$
So we need $3$ iterations to get to relative error of $10^{-8}$. I don't have time right now to explain my original approximation, here is a test program:

```
module sqrtmod
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit  none
   private
   public mysqrt
   contains
      function mysqrt(x) bind(C,name='mysqrt')
         real(REAL64) mysqrt
         real(REAL64),value :: x
         integer(INT64), parameter :: magic = int(Z'3feed9eba10e6360',INT64)
         integer i
!! Initial approximation I didn't have time to explain !!
         mysqrt = transfer(shiftr(magic+transfer(x,magic),1),mysqrt)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
         do i = 1, 3
            mysqrt = 0.5_REAL64*(mysqrt+x/mysqrt)
         end do
      end function mysqrt
end module sqrtmod

program sqrt1
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   use sqrtmod
   implicit  none
   integer(INT64) magic
   real(REAL64) x, y, maxerr
   integer(INT64) i, imax
   imax = 10000000
    maxerr = 0
   do i = 0, imax
      x = 1+i*4.0_REAL64/imax
      y = mysqrt(x)
      maxerr = max(maxerr,(y-sqrt(x))/sqrt(x))
   end do
   write(*,*) 'maxerr = ',maxerr
end program sqrt1
```

**EDIT**: A little free time. To get the initial approximation we observe that
$$\sqrt y=y^{1/2}=2^{\frac12\log_2y}$$
So if we could somehow take the base $2$ logarithm of $y$, divide it by $2$, and then take $2$ to that power, we would have a good approximation to, in fact exactly, $\sqrt y$. Well, as an $\text{IEEE-754}$ double precision floating point number, the base $2$ logarithm is available as bits $52:62$ of $y$. To divide by $2$ we just shift the bits of the representation right by $1$. Then raising $2$ to that power means just interpreting the result as a floating point number once again.

Now, it's a little more complicated than that because the exponent has a bias and there is an implicit leading bit in the mantissa and shifting the mantissa right by $1$ doesn't take its square root! So we have to add a magic number to the integer that represents $y$ as a floating point number to even get in the ballpark but the initial value $x_0$ that we end up with is within about $3\%$ of the exact value.

Let's show a little example of how this works. Start with $y=\frac{\pi^2}8$
$$\begin{align}
y &=  1.2337005501361697\\
y &= \mathtt{\text{ 3FF3BD3CC9BE45DE}}\\
\text{magic} &= \mathtt{\text{ 3FEED9EBA10E6360}}\\
y+\text{magic} &= \mathtt{\text{ 7FE297286ACCA93E}}\\
(y+\text{magic})/2 &= \mathtt{\text{ 3FF14B943566549F}}\\
x_0 &=  1.0809518896033194\\
\sqrt y &=  1.1107207345395915\\
\text{% error} &=  2.68\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you explain how do we have a linear difference equation for $Z_n$? Why does taking $Z_n=\ln e^n$ make it a LDE?

Comment: $$\begin{align}\ln e_{n+1}&=2\ln e_n-\ln2\\Z_{n+1}&=2Z_n-\ln2\end{align}$$ I derived the first equation in the paragraph above and the substitution $Z_n=\ln e_n$ just changed it into the second equation. So it wasn't really anything new, just the same difference equation but written in standard form. Given such a familiar setting we were able to solve it and then express the solution in the context of $e_n$. BTW, in your comment you have $e^n$ 'relative error to the $n^{\text{th}}$ power' but it should be $e_n$ 'relative error after $n$ iterations'. Hopefully just a typo?

Comment: Yes a typo. But I don't understand why the first equation is a difference equation?

Comment: I don't know what to say about that. If you look in the [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Difference_equation) equation (3) matches our format for a difference equation and equation (4) that of a linear difference equation. Even if the definition is unfamiliar hopefully you can follow the solution technique and verify that my final expression for $e_n$ is valid.